# Does $a_0+\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n+a_{-n})=\sum \limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}a_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let we have series $a_0+\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n+a_{-n})$. Why it's equal to $\sum \limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}a_n$?

I guess that for this manipulation me must know something about convergence.

Can anyone explain it rigorously please?

**P.S.** this topic related with Fourier series when they define series $\sum \limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}c_ne^{inx}$. So I guess that this summation understand as limit of $\sum \limits_{n=-N}^{N}a_n$ as $N\to \infty$

Comment: How do you define $\sum \limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}a_n$?

Comment: All the same terms are on both sides so the only issues can be definition and convergence.  Suppose $a_0=0$ and $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ otherwise: the left-hand side is then the sum of a countable number of $0$s but what is the right-hand side?

Comment: Considering $a_n=n$ should demonstrate that the series needn't be the same.

Comment: @Wojowu, this topic related with Fourier series when they define series $\sum \limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}c_ne^{inx}$. So I guess that this summation understand as limit of $\sum \limits_{n=-N}^{N}a_n$ as $N\to \infty$.

Comment: One often requires $$\lim_{M\to\infty,N\to\infty} \sum_{n=-M}^{N}a_n$$ to exist, which is stronger than only using symmetric limits.

Comment: @MPW, if we require an symmetric limit. Is above assumption correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of requiring symmetric limits, they are the same. Just consider the partial sums:

$$S_N = a_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{N} (a_n + a_{-n})$$
and
$$T_N = \sum_{n=-N}^{N} a_n$$
both are the sum of exactly the same $N+1$ terms. So the limits are identical (or fail to exist identically). (Recall that an "infinite sum" isn't really a sum -- it is always a limit of partial sums.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Nice answer! +1

Comment: This is mathematically correct, of course, but in my experience taking symmetric limits is not the definition of convergence of a doubly-infinite sum, just as convergence of an integral over the entire line is not defined by convergence of the principal value.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang : Yes, I agree. +1. I was going to comment that the symmetric case is something of a P-value for the sum, and not what I would consider sufficient for convergence; however, that's what OP specifies.

Comment: Ah right, (+1). :) I mis-read the OP as starting with the doubly-infinite series.

Answer (score 2):

In general,
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_{n}
  = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} a_{n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}
  = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{-n} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n},
\tag{1}
$$
in the sense that the doubly-infinite series *converges* if and only if *both singly-infinite series converge*. When that is the case, the standard theorem about adding convegent series guarantees the sum is
$$
a_{0} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_{-n} + a_{n}).
\tag{2}
$$
As multiple comments note, there are doubly-infinite sequences (such as $a_{-n} = -a_{n}$, with $(a_{n})$ your favorite non-summable sequence) for which (2) is not equal to to (1) (because (2) converges and (1) does not).

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
a_0+\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n+a_{-n}) &= a_0 + a_1 + a_{-1} + a_2 + a_{-2} + \ldots\\
&=a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_{-1} + a_{-2} + \ldots\\
&=a_0 + \sum \limits_{n=-\infty}^{1} a_n +\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\\
&=\sum \limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_n\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: This only works if we assume absolute convergence.

Comment: You are changing terms in infinite series. I guess that it's illegal.